# Is it possible to Show / Hide custom fields based on picklist values using visual flows?

Tags: custom-field, picklist, page-layout, visual-flows

i have one scenario which is show / Hide Fields in page layout based on picklist values (Note : i already developed one vf page to achieve this but it's not allow me to show in edit mode of record)

So, my question is : Is it Possible to do with Visual Flows ?

help me if somebody aware of this kind of stuff....

Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i search something for this actual scenario and i got it. this is possible with Visual Flows, i have created Total Three Screens and One Decision Element for this.....

If someone have this kind of issue drop here comment i am glad to help you out in the same thing which i was faced.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I have query in Dependent picklist in Salesforce. Is it possible way to show the dependent picklist using php code without apex.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFDC Stack Exchange. If you have a question, please post is as a question rather than an answer. That will give you a much better chance of success.